# Tag rename and synonyms: gnucobol <- opencobol

Tags: support, status-completed, tags, retag-request, synonym-request

I've created the tag [gnu-cobol](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gnu-cobol) some years ago and have chosen this spelling as it was the first package name of GnuCOBOL (formerly OpenCOBOL). As the package name was changed to gnucobol some months ago I propose to rename it by removing the hyphen.

Additionally I propose making the tag with the "old" name [opencobol](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/opencobol) a synonym for this renamed tag:

- It is the same piece of software.
- People that ask for help on OpenCOBOL may find help in gnucobol already.
- It is still useful to have the old name available as people may search it (and obviously still tag).

Comment: Combining similiar tags could be useful

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Makes sense and there have been no objections, so: [done](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/gnucobol/synonyms).